# How to remove trace from the plot

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, scatter-plot

I want to remove NA trace from the plot and the legend below.

```
  plot_ly(data = bData,  x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal,  type = 'scatter', mode='markers',  
              symbol = ~Sym,  symbols = c('circle-open','x-open','diamond-open') ,
              text = ~paste(" Security: ", bData$Security, "<br>",
                            "Currency: ", bData$Crncy, "<br>",
                            "YTM: ", bData$YTM,"<br>",
                            "DM: ", bData$DM) ,
              hoverinfo = 'text',legendgroup = 'group1'
      ) %>%
        add_trace(x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal , symbol=~Crncy,legendgroup = 'group2')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You can isolate data without any value in a new dataframe and then plot it. In this example I will omit the `None` value in `Sym` variable but if you have `NA` use `!is.na()` as I also added in a new line of code for you. Here the code:

```
library(plotly)
#New data example
bData2 <- bData[bData$Sym!='None',]
#For your real data
bData2 <- bData[!is.na(bData$Sym),]
#Code
plot_ly(data = bData2,  x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal,  type = 'scatter', mode='markers',  
        symbol = ~Sym,  symbols = c('circle-open','x-open','diamond-open') ,
        text = ~paste(" Security: ", bData2$Security, "<br>",
                      "Currency: ", bData2$Crncy, "<br>",
                      "YTM: ", bData2$YTM,"<br>",
                      "DM: ", bData2$DM) ,
        hoverinfo = 'text',legendgroup = 'group1'
) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal , symbol=~Crncy,legendgroup = 'group2')
```

Output omitting `None`:

[image]

**Update:** Try this hack, replace the values belonging to the `None` class with `NA`, transforming first the factor to character and then again come back to factor. Real `NA` will be dropped by `plotly` functions. Here the code:

```
#Replace
bData$Sym <- as.character(bData$Sym)
bData$Sym[bData$Sym=='None']<-NA
bData$Sym <- as.factor(bData$Sym)
#Code
plot_ly(data = bData,  x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal,  type = 'scatter', mode='markers',  
        symbol = ~Sym,  symbols = c('circle-open','x-open','diamond-open') ,
        text = ~paste(" Security: ", bData$Security, "<br>",
                      "Currency: ", bData$Crncy, "<br>",
                      "YTM: ", bData$YTM,"<br>",
                      "DM: ", bData$DM) ,
        hoverinfo = 'text',legendgroup = 'group1'
) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal , symbol=~Crncy,legendgroup = 'group2')
```

Output:

[image]

Or also try this, duplicating `YVal` and setting `NA` for the first variable:

```
#Replace 2
bData$YVal2 <- bData$YVal
bData$Sym <- as.character(bData$Sym)
bData$Sym[bData$Sym=='None']<-NA
bData$YVal[is.na(bData$Sym)]<-NA
bData$Sym <- as.factor(bData$Sym)
#Code
plot_ly(data = bData,  x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal,  type = 'scatter', mode='markers',  
        symbol = ~Sym,  symbols = c('circle-open','x-open','diamond-open') ,
        text = ~paste(" Security: ", bData$Security, "<br>",
                      "Currency: ", bData$Crncy, "<br>",
                      "YTM: ", bData$YTM,"<br>",
                      "DM: ", bData$DM) ,
        hoverinfo = 'text',legendgroup = 'group1'
) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal2 , symbol=~Crncy,legendgroup = 'group2')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Actually for the second trace the data source should be bData instead of bData2 since bData2 is subset of bData it would miss out on some currencies which have NA in bData$Sym == NA

Comment: @AriKari That is a valid observation, you can play with that or try `na.omit()` or `complete.cases()`. You did no provide your new data so I was not able to reproduce the issue properly. If you want you can share the new data you used in your new plot!

Comment: @AriKari If you share the new data let me know !

Comment: new data is same as the one I shared in earlier question except instead of None it is NA

Comment: @AriKari I have added an update, could you please check if that works for you?